# I'm able to configure Eclipse but the frontend IDE is not shown

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse launch was exiting with an error code -1. This was fixed by giving the correct JVM path in config file of Eclipse. Now, When I try launching Eclipse, front end is not loaded but the java.exe is executed and gets killed by itself.

Can someone please help me on this?

I'm using Eclipse equinox

Comment: can you please post your eclipse.ini ?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the command line and running

```
eclipse.exe -consoleLog
```

that should dump more information out to the command line for you.